# How to mock a property injected by ember's IoC

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js

I'm looking for, how to mock a property injected by the ember's ioc container. The goal is to unit test an class.
For example, I want to test a controller with many injected properties, I can inject in it's container some "controller:NAME" to mock the needed controllers, but how to mock the rest ? Please see to code above understand :

```
//=====================================
// Source :
//=====================================

App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs:["application"]
});

App.Session = Em.Object.extend({
  isAlive:true
});

Em.Application.initializer({
    name: "ioc",

    initialize: function(container, application) {
        container.register('session:instance', App.Session);
        container.optionsForType('session', { singleton: true });

        // inject session in all controllers
        container.typeInjection('controller', 'session', 'session:instance');
    }
});

//=====================================
// Test :
//=====================================


App.setupForTesting();

(function(){
  var container, indexCtrl, session;
  module('Test suite',{
    setup:function(){
        container = new Em.Container();
        container.register('session:instance', Em.Object, {singleton:true});
        container.register('controller:index', App.IndexController);
        container.register('controller:application', Em.Object);
        indexCtrl = container.lookup('controller:index');
        session = container.lookup('session:instance');
    }
  });

  test('IndexController IOC tests',function(){
      ok(indexCtrl.get('controllers.application') !== undefined,
         "ApplicationController should not be undefined");
      ok(indexCtrl.get('session') !== undefined, 
         "Session should not be undefined");
  });
})();
```

On the running demo available here : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AjoRUC/28/edit?js,output
You see that the "session" property is not properly mocked, and is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Use your applications container in the test.

```
setup: function() {
  App.reset();
  indexCtrl = App.__container__.lookup('controller:index') 
};
```

App reset will reset your container and run all of your initializes each time it is called. So this will give you a pristine version of the controller with all dependencies injected.

You can also create a controller at test run time with a mock container.

```
setup: function() {
  container = new Em.Container();
  container.register('session:instance', Em.Object, {singleton:true});
  container.register('controller:application', Em.Object);
  indexCtrl = App.IndexController.create({ container: container });
  session = container.lookup('session:instance');
};
```

I wrote an article about unit testing controllers and some methods of injecting and mocking dependencies during test. You can read it here: http://codingvalue.com/blog/testing-emberjs-controllers/

Comment: I have trouble adapting your example onto testing services. Could you give an example for testing a service that has another dependency (in my case another service) injected?